# How to receive $emitted data from child to parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

From the child component, I am emitting an event `fetchtab`, along with some `data` just like that:

```
this.$emit('fetchtab', data);
```

I want that `data` to be assigned to a `currentData` prop of my parent component (the root component).

```
data: {
    currentData: {}
}
```

This `data` is an array of objects. I need to iterate over that array in my parent component:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in currentData">@{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

But I can't figure out how do I fill in the `currentData` in the first place. I know I could use a) `@fetchtab="myMethod"` or, b) `this.$on('fetchtab', fn)`

But where and how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the @fetchtab event in your parent component as:

`<parent-component @fetchtab="myMethod"></parent-component>`

For more details have a look at [Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

Comment: I made a terrible mistake. I will update my question shortly.